# How to get country code from object in php?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in php/laravel.

I have array with objects

This is sample object:

```
Geocoder\Provider\Nominatim\Model\NominatimAddress Object
(
    [attribution:Geocoder\Provider\Nominatim\Model\NominatimAddress:private] => Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright
    [category:Geocoder\Provider\Nominatim\Model\NominatimAddress:private] => boundary
    [displayName:Geocoder\Provider\Nominatim\Model\NominatimAddress:private] => Rumo, Comunità della Val di Non, TN, TAA, Italia
    [osmType:Geocoder\Provider\Nominatim\Model\NominatimAddress:private] => relation
    [osmId:Geocoder\Provider\Nominatim\Model\NominatimAddress:private] => 47201
    [type:Geocoder\Provider\Nominatim\Model\NominatimAddress:private] => administrative
    [coordinates:Geocoder\Model\Address:private] => Geocoder\Model\Coordinates Object
        (
            [latitude:Geocoder\Model\Coordinates:private] => 46.4610571
            [longitude:Geocoder\Model\Coordinates:private] => 10.9882457
        )

    [bounds:Geocoder\Model\Address:private] => Geocoder\Model\Bounds Object
        (
            [south:Geocoder\Model\Bounds:private] => 46.4218546
            [west:Geocoder\Model\Bounds:private] => 10.9308997
            [north:Geocoder\Model\Bounds:private] => 46.4840451
            [east:Geocoder\Model\Bounds:private] => 11.0481174
        )

    [streetNumber:Geocoder\Model\Address:private] => 
    [streetName:Geocoder\Model\Address:private] => 
    [subLocality:Geocoder\Model\Address:private] => 
    [locality:Geocoder\Model\Address:private] => Rumo
    [postalCode:Geocoder\Model\Address:private] => 
    [adminLevels:Geocoder\Model\Address:private] => Geocoder\Model\AdminLevelCollection Object
        (
            [adminLevels:Geocoder\Model\AdminLevelCollection:private] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Geocoder\Model\AdminLevel Object
                        (
                            [level:Geocoder\Model\AdminLevel:private] => 1
                            [name:Geocoder\Model\AdminLevel:private] => TAA
                            [code:Geocoder\Model\AdminLevel:private] => 
                        )

                    [2] => Geocoder\Model\AdminLevel Object
                        (
                            [level:Geocoder\Model\AdminLevel:private] => 2
                            [name:Geocoder\Model\AdminLevel:private] => Comunità della Val di Non
                            [code:Geocoder\Model\AdminLevel:private] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [country:Geocoder\Model\Address:private] => Geocoder\Model\Country Object
        (
            [name:Geocoder\Model\Country:private] => Italia
            [code:Geocoder\Model\Country:private] => IT
        )

    [timezone:Geocoder\Model\Address:private] => 
    [providedBy:Geocoder\Model\Address:private] => nominatim
)
```

My php code:

```
foreach (app('geocoder')->geocode($request->input('city'))->get() as $key => $value) {
            //echo $value->country->code;
            echo"<pre>"; print_r($value); echo"</pre>";
        }
```

I want check country code. If country->code == PL - then I hand show text: "It's correct" or if not - then I want show text "wrong".

How can I make it?

I need result:

```
It's correct
It's correct
It's correct
wrong
It's correct
```

etc

How can I make it?

Comment: Sooo.... what is that `print_r` outputting? Because it *looks* like, bar an `if ... else` condition, you're basically there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the coutry code using `Geocoder` use the `StringFormatter` class

```php
$formatter = new \Geocoder\Formatter\StringFormatter();

$countryCode = $formatter->format($location, '%c');
```

there are other usefull format listed in the [Documentation](https://geocoder-php.org/docs/)

- Street Number: %n
- Street Name: %S
- City (Locality): %L
- City District (Sub-Locality): %D
- Zipcode (Postal Code): %z
- Admin Level Name: %A1, %A2, %A3, %A4, %A5
- Admin Level Code: %a1, %a2, %a3, %a4, %a5
- Country: %C
- Country Code: %c
- Timezone: %T

Comment: it's return error: Argument 1 passed to Geocoder\Formatter\StringFormatter::format() must implement interface Geocoder\Location, instance of Illuminate\Support\Collection given, called in /var/www/appname/app/Http/Controllers/FrontendController.php on line 934

Comment: what variable did you put as `$location` ?

Comment: I have this code: $res = app('geocoder')->geocode($request->input('city'))->get();
        $formatter = new \Geocoder\Formatter\StringFormatter();
        $countryCode = $formatter->format($res, '%c');

Comment: @goslscs give it a single result `foreach(.... as $value) {$formatter->format($value,'%c');`